# Using AMD and Moodle

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, moodle, amd

I am trying to use jQuery in a module I am building for Moodle but I am facing a lot of problems.

Based on the quide here [Moodle Docs](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Javascript_Modules#Embedding_AMD_code_in_a_page) I created the folder structure required

```
./
./amd
./amd/src
./amd/src/scripts.js
```

And in my scripts.js I have simple code

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {
  return {
    debug: function($){
      console.log($);
    }
  };
});
```

I run grunt, everything compiles as expected.

Then in my PHP I call

```
$PAGE->requires->js_call_amd("mod_mymod/scripts", "debug", null);
```

When I run this I get the following error

> Uncaught Error: No define call for mod_mymod/scripts

Can anybody help me to resolve this?

I never used AMD before, so if for example I need to make something like

```
$("#link").click(function(){
    $(".results").html("hi");
}
```

how I will do it?

Comment: Did you purge all you caches (or set $CFG->jsrev = -1; in config.php)?

Comment: Whoa thanks, I didnt know that :s I mean I had theme designer on but nothing was happening.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {
  return {
    debug: function(){
      console.log($);
    }
  };
});
```

and call it

```
$PAGE->requires->js_call_amd("mod_mymod/scripts", "debug");
```

and make sure that grunt works correctly and creates build folder and scripts.min.js file.

Comment: Notice he originally had a ($) which would replace the jquery $